# Prevent FullSimplify from converting trigonometric expressions to exponential

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

There's an option for `FullSimplify`, which is `Trig`, and with it I could prevent a trigonometric identities from being used.

I'm looking for a similar option that would prevent `FullSimplify` from using the Euler formula

```
Sin[x] -> 1/2/I (Exp[x] - Exp[-x])
Cos[x] -> 1/2   (Exp[x] + Exp[-x])
```

So I want `FullSimplify` to retain `Sin` and `Cos` functions and to use trig identities, but no conversions to `Exp`.

#### Edit

Example as requested from a comment:

```
Cos[2 B g t] Sin[u]^2 - I Sin[2 B g t] Sin[u]^2
```

In this formula, I want `FullSimplify` not to convert `Cos[2 B g t] - I Sin[2 B g t]` to `Exp[-2IBgT]`.

Comment: A small example that shows the problem you have?

Comment: @Nasser example given.

Comment: `Simplify[TrigReduce[s]]` gives `(Cos[2 B g t] - I Sin[2 B g t]) Sin[u]^2`  but this might not generalize without more testing...

Comment: @Nasser This occurred to me actually, but is this as powerful as FullSimplify[] in everything? I mean I could probably need more functions that are not available in Simplify[].

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
 expr = Cos[2 B g t] Sin[u]^2 - I Sin[2 B g t] Sin[u]^2
```

... one approach is:

```
 FullSimplify[expr, ExcludedForms -> {Cos[_], Sin[_]}]
```

> (Cos[2 B g t] - I Sin[2 B g t]) Sin[u]^2

---

Another approach worth exploring is to use a custom `ComplexityFunction`, as per:

```
FF[ee_] := 1000 Count[ee, _Exp, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[ee] 

FullSimplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> FF]
```

Alas, the latter is not working as I might have expected, which is perhaps of interest in its own right.